# I want to store the whole string in a variable except first two words in a text in PHP?

Tags: php, string, explode

Suppose I have a text `Hello Himanshu How are you, Hope all well`.

I have stored it in a variable `$content`, i.e `$content= "Hello Himanshu How are you, Hope all well"`.

I want to store first word in 1 variable, second word in second variable and the rest of the text in third.

I have used explode function in PHP to store 1st two in separate variables, but i am not getting how to store the rest string in a single variable.

```
$arr=explode(' ',trim($content));

$word1=$arr[0];

$word2=$arr[1];

$rest_words=$arr[2];
```

Desired output:

> $word1 = "Hello"
>
> $word2 ="Himanshu"
>
> $rest_words = "How are you, Hope all well"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
$arr=explode(' ',trim($content),3);
```

Check the `limit` part of [PHP explode Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$content= "Hello Himanshu How are you, Hope all well";
$arr=explode(' ',trim($content),3);
$word1=$arr[0];
$word2=$arr[1];
$rest_words=$arr[2];

echo $word1, "\n", $word2, "\n", $rest_words;
```